# Fast SimpleJSON alternative for C#

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, simplejson

I'm developing apps with Unity + C# and using SimpleJSON to manage configuration data in JSON format. The configuration data contains mixed values types: float, string and bool and is nested.

My application requires to sometimes have several hundred lookups per frame (e.g. jsonObject["userConfig"]["borderStyle"][0]["color"]). I used the Unity profiler to check the performance and recognised that it takes some resources to fetch all that entries from the SimpleJSON object.
Do you know a faster alternative compared to SimpleJSON when it comes to massive read and write actions?

Comment: Have you considered the `System.Text.Json` by Microsoft. Its modern and fast and can also work with `JsonElement` if you don't prefer deserializing to CLR objects. Read more in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json?view=net-6.0)

Comment: Why are you reading from file several hundred times a frame? Does your file actually change that fast from an external source? Could you instead load your file once and use the object in memory to look up?

Comment: thanks a lot! Will check if Microsoft's System.Text.Json is faster.

Comment: I have the JSON object parsed in memory and need to access several hundred values of the JSON object every frame.